# Custom Impulse Response Functions for VAR

Tags: python, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I am working on a VAR model for the Safe Assets in the U.S. economy. The demand for Safe Assets has increased as needs to pledge them as collateral, or the response after the '08 crisis has been risk averse with agents moving to safer assets (also forced by new regulation. The theory is that if the demand for Safe Assets is satisfied it will benefit trade and the overall economy.

I have a dataset with six columns: The stock of Safe Assets (identified by Gary Gorton), ten year Treasury, NGDP, RGDP, Risk Premia and Unemployment.

In this IPython Notebook you can observe my results. http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/BenGosub/bce5ad4d38dba5822391

I have run Augmented Dickey Fuller test for stationarity on first differences, estimated a VAR model and generated Impulse Response Functions.

What I want to do is generate a custom Shock to NGDP in order to measure its effect to the stock of safe assets. The shock to NGDP should be in the amount that would return NGDP to pre-crisis trend.

How can I do this? Maybe if I calculate how many standard deviations NGDP is behind '08 trend I can compute shocks in that amount.

Comment: If you are looking for Python code, that would be off-topic here. But asking how this can be done in principle w/ a VAR model is OK.

Comment: If you have an estimated VAR model, you could in principle calculate the answer to your question. Given the estimated model coefficients, you can calculate how a shock of size 1 (or any other size) will affect all the variables in the system 1, 2 or $h$ periods ahead. Just decide how many periods ahead you wish to achieve the desired effect, and the calculation seems quite straightforward (although perhaps tedious).